# Display opencv's mat (CV_8UC1) in picturebox

Tags: winforms, opencv, picturebox

I apologize for dullness of my question but I have spent about 3 days searching for an answer and still no results. 
I need to display images in PictureBox (Visual Studio 2012) as they are feeded to me from cameras. 
I am using OpenCV cv::mat to store the incoming data, pixelformat is CV_8UC1 (grayscale).

I am using this

```
cams->list[i]->output_Img.convertTo(temp, CV_16UC1);
```

to convert(I hope) my 8bit one channel format to 16bit

and this

```
Bitmap ^srcBmp;
srcBmp = gcnew Bitmap(temp.size().width
,temp.size().height
,temp.step
,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format16bppGrayScale
,(System::IntPtr)temp.data);
```

to get a bitmap which can be displayed in picturebox.

But the picturebox keeps failing to display the image (white box with red x over it).
I had marginal success when I used PixelFormat::Format8bppIndexed,
this displayed the image but not in a grayscalse (colors were present), and I was unable to sucessfully modify the color palette. 
Could somebody help me please?

This is my first time posting here I apologize if the question is posted incorrectly